# CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom returns null

Tags: android, google-maps

hi im currently doing school project and I dont know where I get buggy I dont think that my code is wrong too ,please  help me  this is my codes
this is my whole project the thing I use as guide
drive.google.com/open?id=0B0MY4kATEXqlMDQyZWprRDhmeUU

```
    private void sendRequest() {
    String origin = etOrigin.getText().toString();
    String destination = etDestination.getText().toString();
    String[] destinationArray = {"v.mapa","Vasra","Culiat"};

  if (origin.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter origin address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (destination.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter destination address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

        try {
           new DirectionFinder(this, origin, destinationArray[2]).execute();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    try {
        new DirectionFinder(this, destinationArray[2], destinationArray[1]).execute();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 @Override
public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
for (Route route : routes) {
    Toast.makeText(
            MainActivity.this,
            route.startLocation.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

//THIS NEXT LINES RETURNS ID LIKE Sring, I dont know if cameraupdate know what kind of data type route is trying to throw

```
         googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 16));
    //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(route.duration.text);
    //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3)).setText(route.distance.text);

    originMarkers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue))
            .title(route.startAddress)
            .position(route.startLocation)));
    destinationMarkers.add(googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
            .title(route.endAddress)
            .position(route.endLocation)));

    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
            geodesic(true).
            color(Color.BLUE).
            width(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
        polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));

    polylinePaths.add(googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));

    routes.clear();
}
}
```

THEN I GET THIS ERROR

```
Process: com.hci_thesis.thesis_dolph, PID: 4479  
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference  
at com.hci_thesis.thesis_dolph.MainActivity.onDirectionFinderSuccess(MainActivity.java:269)  
at mods.DirectionFinder.parseJSon(DirectionFinder.java:129)  
at mods.DirectionFinder.access$100(DirectionFinder.java:25)  
at mods.DirectionFinder$DownloadRawData.onPostExecute(DirectionFinder.java:87)  
at mods.DirectionFinder$DownloadRawData.onPostExecute(DirectionFinder.java:58)  
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)  
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)  
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`NullPointerException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:

- Calling the instance method of a null object.
- Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
- Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
- Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
- Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

So for your case you get an error in this part of your code `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom`. You can check in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#newLatLngZoom(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng, float)) oh how to properly set the values in this method.

For more information, check this [page](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory) on how to use `CameraUpdateFactory` properly.

Also, check this [part](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#centering_the_map_within_an_area) of Google Maps Android API to check the sample code on how to use this method.